# Need to fill the print statement in python

Tags: python-3.x

Please help me regarding this code. Output should be
`True#False#True#False#True#`

```
for i in [3,1,4,1,5]:
    print()
```

which function has to be used to print the required output...

note: it is in loop but need only one line output

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from the question we want it to be false wherever 1 is there in the list. Also,To get the output in the same line we need to use `end = ' '` in the print statement.

You can try using this code:

```
for i in [3,1,4,1,5]: 
    print(i!=1, end='')
```

which gives an output as: `TrueFalseTrueFalseTrue`

If the `#` has to be considered in between the output you can try using this code:

```
for i in [3,1,4,1,5]: 
    print(i!=1,'#',end='')
```

This will give an output as: `True #False #True #False #True`

Comment: Adding argument `sep=''` will also remove the whitespace between `True`/`False` and `#`